# Apply for working holiday visa with Australia residence

Tags: working-holiday

I'm an Italian currently in Australia with a 485 visa. I'm waiting the 189 invitation, however my current visa will most likely expire before that.
I'm planning to fly to Bali and apply for a working holiday visa (never applied before).
I've lived in Australia for 3 years now and my current residence is in Australia. When I apply for the working holiday visa, they will ask me my current location and my current residence...
Since they don't accept onshore application, do you think this will be a problem? Will it slow down the processing time?
I can't afford to stay in Bali for weeks and all the other Italians I met got their working holiday visas in few minutes after the application (applying from Italy)...

Comment: Questions about long-stay visits are off-topic, here, and need to be asked at [expatriates.se].

Comment: I admit that I know nothing about Australian working holiday visas, so please don't take this as definitive. But the usual reason for this kind of visa is to allow people to experience the country's culture and way of life. Why would they give such a visa to somebody who has already been resident in the country for three years? (Which they will surely know because you already have a long-term visa.) You've already had that experience.

Comment: If you already have a subclass 485 visa, why not get your employer to sponsor you for the [subclass 186](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/employer-nomination-scheme-186) instead?